# Wrapping a instant search with jscript throttle function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, underscore.js

I have the below code of a cloud tag (Goat1000) followed by an instant query. The query portion needs to be wrapped with the throttle function from the underscore.js library. (or my server will keep crashing!)

```
 <script src="underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script src="jquery.tagcanvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function() {
   if( ! $('#myCanvas').tagcanvas({
     textColour : '#000000',
     outlineThickness : 1.5,
     maxSpeed : 0.04,
     depth : 0.25,
     textScale : 5,
     textFont : '"Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif',
     textHeight : 20,
     bgColour : '#FFAF1C', 
     outlineColour : '#4EF2B1',
     bgOutlineThickness : 0,
     freezeDecel : true,
     frontSelect : true,
     wheelZoom : false,
     weight : true

   }))

    {
     // TagCanvas failed to load
     $('#myCanvasContainer').hide();
   }

  //INSERT THE THROTTLE FUNCTION ON THE BELOW INSTANT SEARCH 
  $('#keyword').on('input', function() {
            var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
            if (searchKeyword.length >= 0) {
                $.post('search2.php', { keywords: searchKeyword }, function(data) {
                    $('ul#content').empty()
                    $.each(data, function() {
                        $('ul#content').append('<a href="getgift2.php?id=' + this.Horse + '">' + this.Horse + '  '+ this.odds+' ' + this.trkfullnm +'</a><br /><br />');
                    });
                }, "json");
            }
        });



     });

 </script>
```

Comment: What's your question? Besides, you are including two script tags within a script tag.

Comment: Thx - caught that - paste error. var throttled = _.throttle(InsantSearch, 100);
$(window).scroll(throttled);    I can't get the throttling of the Instant Search to work. The throttled function has to be properly placed somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting your question as more of "How do I use underscore.js's throttle function"

If you visit [throttle](http://underscorejs.org/#throttle) on the underscore docs this is what it says as of the writing of this post.

### Throttle

```
_.throttle(function, wait, [options])
```

> Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with.
>
> By default, throttle will execute the function as soon as you call it for the first time, and, if you call it again any number of times during the wait period, as soon as that period is over. If you'd like to disable the leading-edge call, pass {leading: false}, and if you'd like to disable the execution on the trailing-edge, pass 
>   {trailing: false}.

```
var throttled =  `_.throttle(updatePosition, 100);`

$(window).scroll(throttled);`
```

### My interpretation

It can be a little difficult to interpret the docs. I feel these docs are very terse in their explanation of how the methods work. I would first look at the function signature `_.throttle(function, wait, [options])` this tells you the first argument is a function and if you've worked with JavaScript you have probably noticed that functions can be passed to other functions. A function that  that either returns a function or accepts a function as a parameter is a higher-order function. Almost all underscore.js methods are higher-order functions. The functions second parameter is a wait interval in milliseconds kind of like `settimeout`'s 2nd and last parameter. The last parameter has brackets around it which means it is optional. The last parameter is an options object if you read the description the default options are `{trailing: true, leading: true}` and you can override them with sending in an object as the third argument with trailing false or leading false.

Now the description. It says "Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function,". This function is what I guess you could call a "true" higher-order function, because it both accepts a function as it's parameter and returns a function. If you read the rest of the docs you learn a lot more about how its functionality is I figured you understood it's functionality on throttling so I feel it unnecessary to explain here. The docs infer to you that `throttle` returns a new function which passes all its arguments along to your passed in function while throttling it.

So to use the throttle method. You call the method as the signature states, and then assign the result of the throttle call to a variable and then use that variable any place you would use the regular function. (see example 2) You could also use the method directly where you would use your regular function at without assigning it to a variable. (see example 1)

### Examples

**Example 1**

```
...    

$('#keyword').on('input', _.throttle(function(e) {
    var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
    ...
}, 1000));
```

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/finiso/1/edit?js,console,output)

or alternatively and more like the docs example.

**Example 2**

```
...

function InstantSearch (e) {
    var searchKeyword = $(this).val();
    ...
}

var throttledInstantSearch = _.throttle(InstantSearch, 1000)

$('#keyword').on('input', throttledInstantSearch);
```

[JS Bin Demo](http://jsbin.com/copuzi/1/edit?js,console,output)

Feel free to leave a comment if you have any questions or clarifications.

Comment: Thanks so much John!

Comment: @DatsIntAString no problem!